# How to make Sp backup folder as .bak extension?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Yesterday I took a backup of our SharePoint website using Central Administration, but as everyone knows that we need to create one folder for path where we have to store the backup.

And in that folder we get many files as **.bak** format.

but when I want to restore it then I heard we have to give folder name that contains **.bak** extension

[image]

Please can anyone tell me how to make my marked folder as BAK file as responsiveen.bak in image

Answer (score 0):

No , the folder name doesn't need to have this kind of extensions simply the backup files should be .bak files or .cmp files which we'll be using to restore the site using power shell or CA UI

Comment: Thanks for your response, But may I please know how do I have to add file path using powershell for restoring this backup??

Comment: And if I want to store my backup as [.bak] extension may I please know how to do that?
Because this is the requirement from our management, I dont know why they want it in that particular format.

Comment: If you want to take the backup of a site collection you can use Backup-SPSite "url of site" -path "c://backup/site1.bak" in powershell which will give you the backup of the site collection with .bak extension

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation, just one doubt
Dont I have to create a folder first then give that path in Powershell command??
or directly I can metion backup(Folder)/nameoffile.bak???

Comment: create a folder and give the path in the powershell commands